# PHP parse ini file that includes variables

Tags: php, ini

I try to store different languages in .ini files.

language_en.ini :

```
HELLO_MSG = "Hello $user ! How are you ?"
```

php file

```
$user = "Mike";
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("language_en.ini");
echo $ini_array['HELLO_MSG'];
```

Output

```
Hello Mike ! How are you ?
```

Is it possible to use the $user variable that i set in the ini file or do get just an array with strings if i read in the .ini file with the "parse_ini_file" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be relying on *variable interpolation* for this anyway. You do not define a variable `$user` in this file, how can you expect it to be interpolated at any point? Will you define all possible variables before parsing the ini file? That's a mess!

The standard solution to this is [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$hello = "Hello %s! How are you?";
$message = sprintf($hello, $user);
echo $message;
```

Further, it seems what you're trying to reinvent here is [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) for localisation. Read [this](http://pology.nedohodnik.net//doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html) to realise why you want an existing system like gettext, not an ini file.

Comment: Ooh great, "sprintf" is the solution i was looking for !